# Signature Image Disappeared in Gmail

Tags: image, gmail

I have run into some strange problem with my Gmail account. For all my old/existing emails, the image in the signature is not appearing at all. Upon checking I get this URL in which the image is missing and shows a 404 error

https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/mail-sig/AIorK4zmEcVceLzlQD9FpU7W0I5_9HteAxODTV_jJJu0FLlV6G3hZKjTaN6cXAuvnTQhEHQt7ecxtY

Error Image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCJ57.png

Please help!

Comment: I have the same problem. Sad that gmail doesn't care to support the integrity of past emails or offer any warning about this.